# Web scraping options

Tags: python

Could you recommend me some ways to scrape data from a web page?

I have been trying to use Python but I am stuck with my code. I was thinking about using Octoparse. This is the webpage (http://www.mlsa.am/?page_id=368), it is a drop-down list where the selection of a previous case allows you to choose other options in the other cases.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `scrapy framework` specially built for scraping purpose only.

As an starter you can start from official documentation & you will find everything you need from it.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

except `scrapy` you can use `beautifulsoup` also.